# Android Studio 2.1 update conflict

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-2.0, android-studio-2.1

I am getting conflict while updating **Android Studio 2.1** as below:

[image]

After updating 60-70% I got this error. It has removed **studio-64.exe** automatically So I have copied from another copy of **Android Studio**.

Why it is so? Any Solution? Now what can I do?

Comment: There is no error visible in the screenshoted list. What is failing?
You can safely uninstall and install Android Studio again without loosing your settings.

Answer (score 0):

I removed old android studio completely and downloaded my **Android Studio 2.1** from [Official Site.](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/sdk/index.html)

As I have old settings so imported all the settings from **.AndroidStudio2.0** folder and It works fine.

Thank you.